# How to read a string from a certain word onward in java?

Tags: java, android

I want to use the uri value of an image (location on disk) in my app. For that, I have to use a string that starts with /sdcard/...

I can open up a file manager to help select the picture, but even so every file manager adds something to the front, be it /mnt/sdcard or something else. I can't use substring because the number of letters in front of /sdcard isn't always the same.

I want to read this string from /sdcard onward, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: **string.replace("/sdcard", "/sdcard" + uri)** ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to find the last occurance of "/sdcard" and then read the rest using usual substring from index+offset ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like so:

```
    File cacheDir;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                getString(R.string.cache_directory_image_cache));
    } else {
        cacheDir = getCacheDir();
    }

    String filepath = cacheDir.getAbsolutePath();
```

Then you have the path in filepath!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Seems like a pretty simple question, use indexOf("/sdcard") to find the position of "/sdcard", then initiate your substring from that point.

String#substring( String#indexOf("/sdcard"), String#length() )

Answer (score 0):

U can use the Function

**indexOf(String str)**

where str is '/sdcard/'

this will give you the index of first occurrence of your string.